# I'm using NavigationView on a embedded layout, I'm trying to transfert the layout to another layout bu it crash

Tags: mapbox-android

I'm trying to use the NavigationView on a embedded layout and trying to "move" the layout to another contentview, but it crash has soon I remove the View from the parent with:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.MultiOnClickListener.clearListeners()' on a null object reference]
```

I have a simple class with:

```
public class clsNavigationView extends CoordinatorLayout implements OnNavigationReadyCallback, MapboxMap.OnMapLongClickListener,
        NavigationListener, ProgressChangeListener, InstructionListListener, SpeechAnnouncementListener,
        BannerInstructionsListener, OnTrackingModeChangedListener
...
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.mapbox_activity_embedded_navigation, this);
...
```

The layout have

```
    <com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:navigationDarkTheme="@style/NavigationViewDark"
    app:navigationLightTheme="@style/NavigationViewLight"/>
```

I put the clsNavigationView on a static FrameLayout, I add it to my mainView on another FrameLayout.

When I change view, I remove the view with:

```
((FrameLayout) objFrameMap.getParent()).removeView(objFrameMap);
```

Do my new setContentview on my main Activity.

Then I add back my Frame into my new FrameLayout on the new Content

```
((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.layer_mapview)).addView(objFrameMap);
```

It crash at the removeView, what can I do for fixing that? 
What is the best way for "move" a NavigationView without crashing?

** I'm not using fragment.